# How to get a refresh token and access token in office 365 using PHP

Tags: php, api, office365

May i know how to get refresh token for my account ,If i have refresh token using that how could access my new access token.

Comment: check this : http://www.onlinecode.org/access-token-office-365-using-php/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the Graph API documentation, it show you how to use the OAuth2 authentication to login to your app, and get a refresh token.

https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/app_authorization

You still have to write your own http request to get the access token, but that should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, According to the link I followed the steps at the point I tried to register app, it need credit card verification and then only I would register my app in the Azure active directory. I have been using trial account and I had got access token, but refresh token was not available in that response. Finally I would like to ask questions whether the trial account doesn't show a field of refresh token or not?

Comment: You need to post more information about your setup, and code before i'm able to help you out, right now it's just guessing and it would be way better if I had additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I referred the below link for my code development work and also to make a setup for my app.      

                                                                                                           
https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php#

Comment: You need to make an app in Azure AD, and to do that you might need to make a credit card verification. But the Azure AD doesn't cost anything it is free up to a certain size. Check out this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

Comment: Thanks for your help . I already visited that link and I came to solution after verification only i could access token and refresh token.

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer, this will make it easier for other people to see what helped you out.

Comment: link is broken :-(

Answer (score 4):

We can get access and refresh token without registering Azure AD portal and without providing credit card details.
Please set **"offline_access"** as part of **"scope"** which will return access token and refresh token.
More detail refer here [OAuth2 at Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user)